# How can I get several characters from a std::string

Tags: c++, string

I want to name a file according to the date and the time it was created. I'm using this code to get the date and time:

```
auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::time_t end_time = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time);
std::string finaltime = std::ctime(&end_time);
```

I now want to eliminate all spaces and informations that I dont need from the `finaltime`-string . For this purpose I found out which characters I need.  I need all except 11, 14, 17 (counter started at 0 for the first character).

In python there is a very simple way to do something like that, if you need all characters from 2 to 5 you can say `mystring[2:5]`. Is there somethig similar in c++ or is there another way to delete the chars I need

Comment: There is a [std::string::substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) member function.

Comment: There is also a pretty obvious [`erase` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase)  for removing characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the substr(a, b) [function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)

```
std::string str2 = finaltime.substr (3,5);     // 12:00
```

Comment: One note: [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) in C++ has different arguments, as the substring notation in python - you should note that in the answer.